# Which model with multiple samples by subject and one response by subject? glme?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, model

I have a few variables (continuous or ordinal) and multiple samples from the same subjects (n=10 for now). The number of samples by subject varies from 1 to 50. Samples are not repeated measure s in space and time.
I would like to know if there is a relationship between the response (binary) to a treatment and some measured variables and to make a model that predict response for new subject. To be clear, the response is associated with a subject (not the sample): the subject respond or not to the treatment.

I’m not a statistician but I guess that making a simple logistic regression (even weighted ) is not accurate as the multiple samples by subject might not be independent and prediction of response with new subjects with multiple samples will not be possible. So I start looking at Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Models, but in all the examples I found the samples of a same subject can have different treatment response. So is glme a good model in my case? If not what would be the good model?

I probably can summarize the sample from the same subject (not that easy with ordinal variables) but I feel I could lose information and statistical power.

Thanks a lot.

This is my R code:

```
library(lme4)
ml <- glmer(response~var1+var2+var3+ (1|subject), family=binomial(link="logit"), DATA)
```

Comment: Your response is measured just once for each subject? What about the variables var1 to var3 - are they measured for each sample coming from the same subject? What do these samples represent for each subject? Are they taken from different parts of the same organ, for example? Is the response to treatment decided in any way based on the values of var1 to var3?  Can you give more details about var1 to var3 (e.g., meaning, scale of measurement? Same for response - what is its meaning/scale of measurement?

Comment: Thanks Isabella. Yes the response is measured just once for each subject. All vars are measured in each sample. The samples are lymph nodes: small organs from lymphatic system. They are more or less related to each other. And no the response is not based on the lymph nodes. The vars (more than 3) can be integers, numeric or ordinal (from0 to 3). Response is binary.